# Losing focus at buttons in android application

Tags: android

I made one simple android application and I notice next problem:
I have several controls with attached click (or i say touch) event (buttons, imageviews). Some of them are loaded from android xml file, and some I make "in fly".

Now when I scroll screen, I must 2 time click on button to make effect (click event). It seems to me that this have some connection with losing focus. 
Am I right and how to solve it? I want just one click to execute some operation.

This happen only on real device (HTC Wildfire). In emulator there is no this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you, by any chance, have

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

for the Button? Because this will cause the button to need one touch to gain focus and another one to fire the click.